# angularjs custom form and field directive: ngModelController is not found in FormController

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have 2 directives, one is my-form, one is my-field. 
**I need to use the mode of dynamically creating the html content for both of these two directives.**
Everything works well except I can not get the ngModelController of the input fields.
So I can not get the $dirty, $valid properties of these fields.
For example, when submitting, I want to get the ngModelController of the input with name "field1", but I can not get it.
form.field1 is undefined.
In the FormController "form1", there is no field, any one can help on this?
Many thanks

the code in fiddle is:
https://jsfiddle.net/0td5hLur/3/

main codes are also listed below:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
                .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                    $scope.config = {
                        name: 'form1',
                        fields: [
                            {type: 'text', name: 'field1', model: 'obj.field1'},
                            {type: 'text', name: 'field2', model: 'obj.field2'}
                        ]
                    };
                }])
                .directive('myForm', ['$compile', function($compile) {
                    return {
                        restrict: 'E',
                        replace: true,
                        scope: {
                            config: '='
                        },
                        compile: function(element, attrs, transclude) {
                            return {
                                pre: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                                    console.log('-------myForm');
                                    var html = '<form name="{{config.name}}">' +
                                            '   <my-field ng-repeat="item in config.fields" config="item"></my-field>' +
                                            '    <button ng-click="submit()">submit</button>' +
                                            '</form>';
                                    iElement.append($compile(html)(scope));
                                    scope.obj = {
                                        field1: '1',
                                        field2: '2'
                                    };
                                    scope.submit = function () {
                                        var form = scope[scope.config.name];
                                        console.log(form);
                                        alert(form.field1);
                                        alert(form.field1.$dirty);        // error here
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                        }
                    }
                    }])
                        .directive('myField', ['$compile', function($compile) {
                            return {
                                restrict: 'E',
                                replace: true,
                                scope: {
                                    config: '='
                                },
                                compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
                                    return {
                                        pre: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                                            var config = scope.config;
                                            var html = '<input type="' + config.type + '" ng-model="' + config.model + '" name="' + config.name + '" />';
                                            iElement.after($compile(html)(scope.$parent));
                                            iElement.remove();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }])
        ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <my-form config="config"></my-form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it out myself, only modified several lines but it was really not a easy job.
The final working codes are as below:
What I missed are below lines:
**iElement.after(html);

var element = iElement.next();

iElement.remove();

$compile(element)(scope.$parent);**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.config = {
    name: 'form1',
    fields: [
      {type: 'text', name: 'field1', model: 'obj.field1'},
      {type: 'text', name: 'field2', model: 'obj.field2'}
    ]
  };
}])
.directive('myForm', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      config: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
      console.log('-------myForm');
      var html = '<form name="{{config.name}}">' +
          '   <my-field ng-repeat="item in config.fields" config="item"></my-field>' +
          '    <button ng-click="submit()">submit</button>' +
          '</form>';
      iElement.append($compile(html)(scope));
      scope.obj = {
        field1: '1',
        field2: '2'
      };
      scope.submit = function () {
        var form = scope[scope.config.name];
        console.log(form);
        alert(form.field1);
        alert(form.field1.$dirty);        // error here
      }
    }
  }
}])
.directive('myField', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      config: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
      var config = scope.config;
      var html = '<input type="' + config.type + '" ng-model="' + config.model + '" name="' + config.name + '" />';
      iElement.after(html);
      var element = iElement.next();
      iElement.remove();
      $compile(element)(scope.$parent);
    }
  }
}])
        ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <my-form config="config"></my-form>
</div>
```